# Get all elements from a specific namespace in an XML document

Tags: javascript, xml

i need to get the element of an XML-File by the prefix. My XML-File looks like:

```
<dependency:COP xmi:id="5299" sofa="6" begin="291" end="294" Governor="4906" Dependent="4928" DependencyType="cop"/>
<dependency:POSS xmi:id="5306" sofa="6" begin="90" end="93" Governor="5313" Dependent="5322" DependencyType="poss"/>
<dependency:POSS xmi:id="5751" sofa="6" begin="133" end="136" Governor="5758" Dependent="5767" DependencyType="poss"/>
<dependency:POSS xmi:id="6385" sofa="6" begin="172" end="175" Governor="6361" Dependent="6352" DependencyType="poss"/>
<dependency:POSS xmi:id="6392" sofa="6" begin="203" end="206" Governor="6234" Dependent="6216" DependencyType="poss"/>
<dependency:POSS xmi:id="6399" sofa="6" begin="362" end="365" Governor="6406" Dependent="6415" DependencyType="poss"/>
<constituent:ADVP xmi:id="5808" sofa="6" begin="149" end="153" constituentType="ADVP" parent="5784" children="5819"/>
<constituent:ADVP xmi:id="4937" sofa="6" begin="295" end="301" constituentType="ADVP" parent="4894" children="4948"/>
<dependency:ADVCL xmi:id="6866" sofa="6" begin="31" end="35" Governor="5499" Dependent="5632" DependencyType="advcl"/>
```

I know there is the function getElementsByTagName, but it wont help me in this case. I want to get all elements with the prefix dependency.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Googling `<name of a programming language you can use> XML  Get element by prefix` will probably get you started.

Comment: I did.. But i didnt find the solution for my problem. They just showed how the prefix and namespace is set.. But never how to search for it.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Javascript. You can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution:

getElementsByTagNameNS(Namespace,"*");

The namespace of dependency is declared on the top of the XML-File.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xPath.

Here is an example to find any element that has an attribute that start with 'poss': `//*[starts-with(@DependencyType,'poss')]`